# for each loop pyton - nested loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, foreach

```
lyrics = ["I want to break free", "I want to break free",
          "I want to break free", "yes, I want to break free"]
number_of_lines = 6
```

I am trying to create a loop that prints as many lines as many number_of_lines. In this specific example I basically need to loop IN lyrics 1.5 times to print the whole list (4 lines) and then the first 2 again to get to 6 = number of lines. How do you do it exactly?

thanks much in advance

```
for line in lyrics:
   print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.cycle` to repeat the contents of the list as often as necessary to obtain the desired number of lines (using `itertools.islice`):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice


lyrics = ["I want to break free", "I want to break free",
          "I want to break free", "yes, I want to break free"]
number_of_lines = 6

for line in islice(cycle(lyrics), 6):
    print(line)
```

---

This incurs some additional memory overhead, though. `cycle` has to cache the values it reads from its iterator in order to repeat them. Just something to keep in mind when using `cycle` and large lists, but typically the lists will be small.

The issue is that `cycle` iterates over an *iterator* it obtains from its iterable argument, and the list behind the iterator could change between calls to `next`. For example,

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> i = cycle(x)
>>> next(i)
1
>>> next(i)
2
>>> x.clear()
>>> next(i)  # Not 3
1
>>> next(i)
2
>>> next(i)
1
```

Comment: My experience with small sizes of lists is that `cycle()` runs faster than an own `while` or the modulo solution. Usually I don't cycle large lists, so I haven't worried about memory.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just thinking, e.g., how `iter(range(BIG_NUM))` would use constant space, but `cycle(range(BIG_NUM))` would use space proportional to how many items from the range you needed iterated over.

Comment: If I have got the documentation the right way `cycle()` builds an own copy of the list. So if you cycle over the full list repeatedly you need twice the space but only for the list structure and not for the items as they are anyway already there addressed by the list.

Comment: How will `iter(range(BIG_NUM)` get the items in the second cycle? Isn't `range` already `iter`?

Comment: `range` is an iterable, but not an iterator. Calling `iter` gives you a value of type `range_iterator` that produces the values using constant space.

Comment: Right, `cycle` basically makes a shallow copy (but only copying the references that actually get requested). That is, `cycle.__next__` will read from its given iterator and save what it gets in memory. Once it exhausts its iterator, it goes back to the start of the cache and yields those values as many times as needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251634/discussion-between-claudio-and-chepner).

Comment: If you know it's a list and want to save memory at the cost of a little(?) speed, you can [repeat the list](https://tio.run/##dZDBasMwEETv@oohJxtEL4VQCv2AfkMpRnbWZOlaq6yVBn@9K9klh9LsSey@GWaUlnzW@PySbF1H0wmcybKqzOApqWXwLDyQx3AOHD2MEoXsnCzGw4w3fBzecQsxIyt6o/CF0YgOHg/2Dvd5qFxo9vj3@OniderJOh074Ug1wdG5SwlWXif@nvTU/EE8hGKzB25bN15Fqmwr9FRLd7V06IWavd0v63EpeA4shd6/4X6x4qOG6g@Ou1ezOXtURfu69UzGsdgVql3XHw).

Comment: Benchmarked with "large" data, I get times like 41 ns / element for yours, 58 for mine, and 132 for just `range`, which @Claudio and Pingu are using (I don't see a nice way to include the rest of what they're doing, so I'll leave it at this, since `range` alone is already that much slower).

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHRbsMgDEXf8xV@K5lYm62qtE3qF0zKLyBGzMpEgBIyqV@fGUi7TlreYl8f34vDJZ2827@EuCw6@hFMwpi8txOYMfiYwEzWKOSgTtI4DhEDykS/F2WxKSPJjHhVB4xaKD87woCcSq@qlLcWVTLe3dADnmdsmgE10TE4jMxOxO7btwboi5jm6FYHrGzMgjYr6tg7Wnv5O3Qmj3CEwXyPfmA9B4uuTLWlrWdL2Y41zjY7Ezmy/CB2zVZx51WfpLEkXz2UVmzv3RUQK1he1Ku1r3lKIkr3if@Gqp2cQ89OVUflCXgNxe8ATUMEUlgzJVYHD13XkcOeqgfRdc@CCoTyEQSYK32/rsxlnctlVa2VbDSdD8TaW6mchOmr5d9GiMbRcrrswFgdgkdILeyghwd4wlc6y4ZuuwO0OKJLsOGgt0I4OaIQlVQp7bL8AA "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: That said, if we wanted to be optimal with speed and memory, we wouldn't construct one iterator but would use two nested lists, to repeatedly iterate over the list directly.

Comment: thak you very much!

Comment: After removing a layer from my iterator, it seems slightly [faster](https://tio.run/##VVFbasMwEPzXKfYvcjGJkxBoAzlBwRcoRSj2qhHo4chyIad3V4@UVn@enZmdWU@PePPu@DqFdVXBW9ARQ/TezKDt5EMEPRs9YAvDTWrXQsAJZaTPx2CQVU7UFnVk2WDwxuAQtXe/FiPeF2RsREUuODkM3Mzk0TdnBvQCxiW4uoln50RoEqPI3tGYx@G/6k5h4AKj/rZ@5H0LBl2WNXmsFkMlLjVwkd7LKEptaFL35Ulo/ibJXbepjkj3kFcKlDGeXVv4SBafdRNTixvSqlqurXEZI2uCjZ4jD9J9IT91XUeqntCT6LqDIIAx5QMI0A4K6VgLJlglOPsXLMcntaUs5erbZ0Fpr6M8l2Nz9bwVHdEt9orhsq9x05uCdpTJL27kEXbQwwvs8Y3IG/ptO0CDFl2ETQtqK4STFoUo8iJt1vUH) than yours (for such larger lists) while still only using constant space.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the modulo operator as follows:

```
lyrics = ["I want to break free", "I want to break free", "I want to break free", "yes, I want to break free"]
number_of_lines = 6

for i in range(number_of_lines):
    print(lyrics[i%len(lyrics)])
```

**Output:**

```
I want to break free
I want to break free
I want to break free
yes, I want to break free
I want to break free
I want to break free
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option (maybe a bit more "Pythonic" as using the modulo operator) is to use the `cycle()` method available in the with Python coming itertools module as follows:

```
lyrics = ["I want to break free", "I want to break free", "I want to break free", "yes, I want to break free"]
number_of_lines = 6

from itertools import cycle
line_in_lyrics_cycle = cycle(lyrics)

for _ in range(number_of_lines):
   print( next(line_in_lyrics_cycle) )
```

And because `line_in_lyrics_cycle` is an iterator you get a line out of it using the Python `next()` method and don't need the index value provided in the loop by `range()`. A nice side-effect here is that because of use of `next()` you can read the code like you would read the explanation what it does.

---

For the sake of completeness here the code proposed by *Kelly Bundy* in comments to the other itertools using answer by *chepner*:

```
from itertools import islice, chain, repeat
q, r = divmod(number_of_lines, len(lyrics))
fulls = chain.from_iterable(repeat(lyrics, q))
tail = islice(lyrics, r)
for line in chain(fulls, tail):
    print(line)
```

which does expressed in terms of Python list only:

```
q, r = divmod(number_of_lines, len(lyrics))
lyrics_total = q*lyrics+lyrics[0:r]
for line in lyrics_total:
    print(line)
```

Looking especially at the first version of the code making full use of the itertools iterators the entire BEAUTY of

```
   print( next(line_in_lyrics_cycle) )
```

is gone, buried so deep under the really hard to understand code, that you need probably three times the lines of text to explain what, how and why just this code.

In this context the code provided by *Pingu* needs much less explanations, because you only have to understand how the modulo `%` operator works and must not worry about `divmod` and/or `itertools`.

It excels because of its shortness got down to the bare point of cycling which the modulo operator is all about:

```
for i in range(number_of_lines):
    print(lyrics[i%len(lyrics)])
```